# React Navigation v3 - Tabs Icon - question mark instead of Icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to add icons to my react-navigation example, which i found from reactnavigation.org:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html

Even this implementation seems not to work properly, because the `Settings` tab shows a question mark for the icon when it is unelected. Here is a snack proving it:
https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/stacks-in-tabs-v3

How can I change the code so that the question mark never appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing everything right! :) The issue is actually with the docs. The reason you're seeing a question mark when `Settings` is not in `focus` is that the icon `ios-options-outline` doesn't exist! Here is the docs example:

```
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge; 
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }
```

When `Settings` is in `focus`, `iconName` will be `ios-options-outline` from `Ionicons`. A quick search of the [icon directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/) shows that while `ios-options` exists, `ios-options-outline` does not.

All you need to do to fix it is choose an icon that exists, or actually don't change the icon based on `focus` at all, since `tint` will signal the selected tab anyway. The following code should work the way you wish.

```
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge; 
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = `ios-options`;
        }
```

I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation.github.io/pull/383) to fix this in the docs so it won't happen to anyone else!